# Proving the limit of a sequence is in its set

Tags: real-analysis

Is my first proof correct?:

If $x_n>2\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $x_n\rightarrow L$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, prove that $L\geq2$.

By the limit definition, $\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$. Suppose $0<L<2$. Choose $\epsilon=2-L$. Then:
$$|x_n-L|=x_n-L<\epsilon=2-L$$
$$\implies x_n<2$$
Which is a contradiction. Then suppose $L<0$. Choose $\epsilon=2+L$ and arrive to a similar conclusion. Is it proved?

Comment: You only need the $\;L<2\;$ case, without limiting $\;0<L\;$ , to reach a contradiction

Comment: Sorry, it's late and I somehow thought that epsilon would then be negative. Is the rest of the proof ok?

Comment: It looks very good to me. BTW, it isn't necessary to require $\;n>2\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N\;$ : it is enough to ask this for all but a finite number of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing $\epsilon=2+L$ is dangerous if $L<0$ since $\epsilon$ could be negative. But, you've already proven it for $L<0$ because nowhere in your proof do you use the fact that $0<L$. You only needed $L<2$ and $x_n>2>L$.

Comment: $2+L$ can be negative when $L<0$. But his two-case proof can still be resucued, if he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine but as a matter of technique, it is usually more promising to choose a more conservative $\epsilon$, in this
 case, say
$$
\epsilon = \frac{2-L}{2}$$.
For example, the proposition you proved is also true if you weaken the condition to be
$\forall n : x_n \geq 2$ (rather than $x>2$), and to prove that, you need to take a more conservative $\epsilon$ than $2-L$.

Answer (score 0):

A marginally different approach:

Suppose $\lambda <2$, and let $\epsilon' = 2-\lambda >0$. Then $x_n-\lambda \ge 2-\lambda = \epsilon' $ and so $|x_n-\lambda| \ge \epsilon'>0$ for all $n$.

Hence $\lambda \neq L$ and so $L \ge 2$.